# How to delete jQuery autocomplete item

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

My JQuery code is:

```
$(function() {
$( document ).tooltip({
  track: true
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
var availableTags = ["Bangladesh","USA","Uk","CANADA","Angola","Antigua and  Barbuda","Argentina"];
var country;
$( "#country_name" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  autoFocus: true,
  select: function( event, ui ) {              
       country=ui.item.value;  //$('#target').text( ui.item.value );
       //$('#div_selected_country').text($('#div_selected_country').html()+"\n "+country);
       $('#div_selected_country').html($('#div_selected_country').html()+"<span>"+country+
            " <a href='?delete=1' class='del_country'>X</a></span>"+"\n ");
       $('#hid_country_names').val($('#div_selected_country').html());
       if ( ui.item ){
          $(this).val('');
          return false;
       }
  }
});
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
//$('a.del_country').click(function(e) {
$('a.del_country').on('click', function() { //.on in JQuery 1.9 and up instead of .live
    alert('sumon');
});
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aminulsumon/nrC3G/13/)

I am trying to implement auto complete for list of countries, add one by one and shows into another div. Up to this point my code works fine, but I need to remove selected countries as well (one by one).

What I have done, when I add a country I include a span tag by mentioning a class; and later when I try to access that class using jQuery, I failed to get that class.

From my understanding, my span tag is not binding properly with HTML DOM and that's why later it's not identified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation approach for `.on()` since the elements with `class="del_country"` are being added dynamically.

```
$(document).on('click','a.del_country', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();/* prevent browser opening href url*/
        /* remove parent span*/
        $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrC3G/14/)**</kbd>

Comment: event delegation works for me and it's what i was exactly looking for. and seems to me, every time if i use this delegation i should not think of html(auto generated)binding.

Comment: if this works, please accept answer. You have asked many many questions and don't appear to ever accept them. WIth this one you never even looked at this answer before creating exact same question a few hours later