# why not my jquery event called for dynamically generated span

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JQuery Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#btnGenSpan').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#div_container").html($("#div_container").html()+
            "<span>Item-01 <a href='?delete=1' class='delete_item'>X</a></span><br />");
  });

  $('a.delete_item').on('click',function(e) {
    alert('delete clicked');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Here is html content:

```
<input type="button" id="btnGenSpan" value="Generate More Item" /><br /><br />
<div id="div_container">
  <span>Default Item-01 <a href='?delete=111' class='delete_item'>X</a></span><br />
  <span>Default Item-02 <a href='?delete=112' class='delete_item'>X</a></span><br />
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aminulsumon/L3h7S/4/)

For static items(Default Item-01 & Default Item-02) X anchor works fine and called delete_item but for those span which are generated by jquery(same html class & anchor generated as default) not called. any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not much point in passing `(e)` if you're not using it.

Comment: don't you look at answers to your questions? gave you this answer 3 hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714059/how-to-delete-jquery-autocomplete-item

Comment: @charlietfl oops... noticed 22 question with not a single accepted answer... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try using event delegation syntax of `on` to have the event available for the dynamically created elements. Reason being your original event is bound only to the `a.delete_item` that already existed in DOM at the time of event binding, so newly added ones just did n't have that event bound to it. So bind the event to the parent container that exists in DOM as long as you need the event so that it gets delegated to the selector (jquery uses event bubbling to make this work) when that event happens.

```
  $('#div_container').on('click','a.delete_item', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('delete clicked');
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5bM8v/)**

Comment: You answer works for me accurately and i am sure i can use it for all further projects.

Answer (score 0):

You must creat event for new DOM
Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#btnGenSpan').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#div_container").html($("#div_container").html()+"<span>Item-01 <a href='?delete=1' class='delete_item'>X</a</span><br />");
      $('a.delete_item').on('click',function(e) {
        alert('delete clicked');
        return false;
      });
  });

  $('a.delete_item').on('click',function(e) {
    alert('delete clicked');
    return false;
  });
});
```